# SQLite using GROUP BY without being case sensitive

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, group-by

I have got a column for Email adresses in my table, where it's possibile for the adresses to be all lower case, all upper case, camelcase, etc.
How can I modify my query so, that adresses like example@gmail.com and EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM will be grouped together.

Thats my actual query:

```
SELECT count(Email) as Number, Email
FROM tbl_SAP_Users
GROUP BY Email
HAVING Number > 1
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [LOWER()](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-lower.php) function to make them all lower case.

You might also want to use [TRIM()](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-trim.php) to address whitespace at either end.

```
SELECT count(Email) as Number, Email
FROM tbl_SAP_Users
GROUP BY LOWER(TRIM(Email))
HAVING Number > 1
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by lower(Email)`:

```
SELECT count(*) as Number, lower(Email) Email
FROM tbl_SAP_Users
GROUP BY lower(Email)
HAVING Number > 1
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

Or use `COLLATE NOCASE` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT count(*) as Number, Email
FROM tbl_SAP_Users
GROUP BY Email COLLATE NOCASE
HAVING Number > 1
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

Comment: This definitly fullfills my needs, but Tom Smallwood also adressed an issue I didn't realize I have. Nonetheless thank you.

Comment: @SebastianS There may be other issues that you did not describe in your question. You don't expect us to guess, do you?

Comment: I don't. If I find some more issues I'll update the question. Or better, I'm looking up how to manipulate the data like with lower() and trim().

Comment: @SebastianS If you *don't* then you should accept the answer that solved the issue that you describe in your question, because if there are leading or trailing spaces in your emails then the GROUP BY clause would group `'a'` and `'a '` in different groups, but this is not what you asked.